# Forgot password API is not working in magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, api

I need to reset the password[Forgot Password] using below  REST API,

URL : `{{base_url}}/index.php/rest/V1/customers/password`

Method : `PUT`

body :

```
{
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "template": "Forgot Password",
    "websiteId": 0
}
```

Getting the  below response,

```
{
  "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue, %field2Name = %field2Value",
  "parameters": {
    "fieldName": "email",
    "fieldValue": "test@gmail.com",
    "field2Name": "websiteId",
    "field2Value": 0
  }
}
```

Please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working when i give template as **email_reset**

```
{
   "email": "test@email.com",
   "template": "email_reset",
   "websiteId": 1
}
```

[The [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html) for this api not correct."**email_reset**" is not real template which you can create in admin. It is constant which I found in AccountManagenet.php]

[Refer](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5513)

Comment: How to get reset password link by rest api. this email_reset only sending change password message.