# Customer Forgot Password Rest Api In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, customer, api

I am using magento 2 rest api,
when I try to run forgot password api for customer, it is showing an error message.

```
{"message":"Invalid value of \"%value\" provided for the %fieldName field.","parameters":{"value":"forgot_password","fieldName":"email type"}
```

I am using below api to send forgot password to user:
**{base-url}/rest/V1/customers/password**

I have created email template with name **forgot_password**

I am sending three parameters:
email,template and website

I would be great if anyone can help.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html  API GET    `/V1/customers/:customerId/password/resetLinkToken/:resetPasswordLinkToken`

Comment: Duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142003/forgot-password-api-is-not-working-in-magento-2-x/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply ankit, i already refer the above question, but problem is different, can you please guid me with my peoblem, what should i do ? should I use above api suggested by you ?

Comment: Can try not sure

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5513

Comment: Hey, when I added email_reset as template it removed error but returns false in response, any clue ?

Comment: Can paste error then try to help

Comment: when I call this api, I print the response, it just print "false".

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me:

```
{
   "email": "email@email.com",
   "template": "email_reset",
   "websiteId": 1
}
```

template - "email_reset" is not real template which you can create in admin. It is constant which I found in AccountManagenet.php.

[Reference](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5513)

Comment: Note that even though you must use "email_reset" for the "template" value, it will actually use your forgot_password template, as long as you have set it up to be the one used for this purpose at Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Password Options > Forgot Email Template

Comment: @Manish, How to get reset password link by rest api. this email_reset only sending change password message.